Comparing odds ratios on same people but from different models
I have run two logistic regression models (two different versions of handling missing data( using the same sample and using the same predictors. I want to compare whether or not the odds ratios for the same predictor differ between the two models. My plan was to simply comparing the overlap (or not) between the 95% CIs. A colleague suggested that I compare the point estimate the OR from each model using an Wald Test. To me, this is largely the same conceptual approach as comparing the two CIs. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Bootstrap both models together (including the process of handling missing data) and compute a bootstrap confidence interval for the difference between the two estimates. Your test of of the difference is whether 0 is within the confidence interval for the difference.

They are not the same. "Do the 95% CIs overlap?" is much more conservative (that is it requires a much bigger difference) than a Wald test or any of the usual statistical tests.
I know there is a good answer about this here, but I don't know good search terms to find it. But, basically, draw the two CIs and look how far apart the centers have to be for the CIs not to overlap. Hypothesis tests are more analogous to one point estimate being outside the other 95% CI, but I'm not sure that's exactly right, either.

I suspect (under the null hypothesis of identical distributions and some other assumptions) the 95% CIs overlap almost 99.5% of the time while at least one point is inside the other's 95% confidence interval about 84% of the time (and both in the other's CI about 83% of the time).   So neither approach is a particularly helpful shortcut.
